# p:inputTextarea in p:tabView save Text to Backingbean

Tags: primefaces

i have a dynamic count of p:tab in my form in every Tab is a p:inputtextarea.
This will works fine but the Text in the InputTextArea will only save to the Backing Bean Value when i take a tabChange Event.

How can i resolve this ?

I wont a save at every onkeyup or a click on the a button.

Answer (score 0):

1. onkeyup: Register the `keyup` ajax event on the inputTextarea:

   ```
   <h:form>
       <p:inputTextarea id="textArea1" value="#{testClazz.testHtml}" >
           <p:ajax event="keyup"/>
       </p:inputTextarea>
   </h:form>
   ```
2. button click: process the inputTextarea

   ```
   <h:form>
       <p:inputTextarea id="textArea2" value="#{testClazz.testHtml}"/>
       <p:commandButton value="Save" process="textArea2"/>
   </h:form>
   ```

Form basic PrimeFaces component examples see the [PrimeFaces ShowCase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf).